# How to use CanActive/ CanDeactive route guard to restrict user to navigate back to open unauthorized pages, after user is logged in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-route-guards

I have two open routes (eg: /home, /details). After user is logged in, I want to restrict the user to go to these pages, till he logout, by direct change in URL, or hitting back button.

I have used AuthGuard, for restricting users to go to protected routes,when he is not logged in.

```
canActivate(
 next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
 state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | 
 boolean {
  if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === null || 
    localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'false') {
    return true;
  }

  this.router.navigate([state.url]);
  return false;
})
```

Comment: create another `guard` that does the opposite of `AuthGuard` and use it on `/home` and `/details`

Comment: Yes, I have done it. The code given is for another guard. Now I want to navigate back to previous state, if user wants to go to open routes without logout. Now using this.router.navigate([state.url]) does not gives me previous state always. Sometimes it gives /

Comment: what you're after here is unclear, try to add more details

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of home and details urls. For example,

```
const restrictedRoutes = ['about',  'details'];
```

And after checking user loggedIn or not, you can add one more condition of checking current routes exist in restrictedRoutes. Based on that you can redirect user to other pages.

```
if (restrictedRoutes.includes(route.url)) {
  // redirect path
}
this.router.navigate([state.url]);
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

// general routes are '/home', '/details'

use a candeactivate authguard in other authenticated routes( where user should be loggedIn). there you can check the condition and reject/redirect.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router} from '@angular/router'; 

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  openRoutes = ['/home', '/details'];
  intendedRoute: string = '';
  constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this.intendedRoute = _router.url;
  }
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
    return this.openRoutes .includes(this.intendedRoute)? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }

}
```

if the condition is true you can cancel navigation by returning false from the canDeactivate method in your respective component.